# don't show backbutton when i use inappbrowser plugin

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

After the `onDeviceReady` event is fired, my app opens an url in the `cordova InAppBrowser`.
Now I want to show a backbutton in the browser.

How can i do this?

This is my code so far:

```
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
            var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://example.com/','_self', 'hardwareback=yes,directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,hardwareback=yes,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no');
            var myCallback = function(event) { 
                cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://example.com/','_self', 'hardwareback=yes,directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no'); }
            ref.addEventListener('exit', myCallback);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Since you tagged your question with `ionic?` Why are you not using it? Here would be an [example](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/)

Comment: I don't think it is possible as the InAppBrowser History is empty, what is the purpose of that?

Comment: need to open a website in application using in app browser and also need to show backbutton to give native look and for user friendly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `_self instead of _blank`

This will open the passed URL in the inappbrowser. 
`cordova.InAppBrowser.open(myURL, '_blank');`

And

`cordova.InAppBrowser.open(myURL, '_self');` it will open the passed URL in the Webview.

Note :: with what Have read,i don't think webview work with back button try using blank